# PHP Prepared statements from web form issues

Tags: php, mysql, webforms, prepared-statement, statements

Only recently started using mysql so I'm slowly getting to grips with it, but trying to use PHP prepared statements for a webform, and upon submitting the webform, it's just displaying the php code. Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "contactform");

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO contactform (firstname, surname, address1, address2, 
towncity, county, postcode) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $firstname, $surname, $address1, 
$address2, $towncity, $county, $postcode);

$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
$surname = $_REQUEST['surname'];
$address1 = $_REQUEST['address1'];
$address2 = $_REQUEST['address2'];
$towncity = $_REQUEST['towncity'];
$county = $_REQUEST['county'];
$postcode = $_REQUEST['postcode'];


if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: So it's displaying the source code?

Comment: Hi Simon,

Yeah thats right. I had it working fine before using prepared statements.

Comment: The only reasons I can think of for it showing the PHP source, is a dodgy opening tag, or your webserver isn't set up properly.

Comment: You should remove this question as there does not seem to be a reproducible problem with the code. Or is there? Then you should post  a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `eval( $text );` will execute your string as PHP code.
is that what you are looking for ?

[PHP eval() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data